# Expressjs Creud database with mongolab

Tags: node.js, express, mlab

Im triyng to find a normal example of working crud w expressjs and a database that It's not obsoleted.

Really makes me say why I dont go back w rails ....

I searched the web forums manuals videos no luck..... that hard It's expressjs database integration ?

Anyone can share w the comunity an express mongolab example crud ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a good practice to put all your db stuff into a separate file that can be reused easily in different projects. Your `db.js` could look like the following:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var db = mongoose.createConnection("mongodb://<db_user>:<db_password>@ds0<db_port>.mongolab.com:<db_port>/<db_name>");

var playerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  tournament: String
});

exports.Player = db.model("player", playerSchema);
```

You just have to substitute the <> fields with your credentials. Then in your main `app.js` create a route for creating a new player (`POST` method).

```
var routes = require('./routes');
app.post("/", routes.createPlayer);
```

And then finally in your `routes.js`

```
var db = require('./db');
exports.createPlayer = function(req, res) {
  var player = new db.Player();
  player.name = req.body.player_name;
  player.tournament = req.body.tournament;
  player.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    res.redirect("/" + player._id);
  });
};
```

The same goes for the other methods (`PUT` -> `UPDATE`, `DEL` and `GET` -> `READ`). For `DEL` and `PUT` you have to override the methods in your client side form (server side automatically done by the `methodOverride` middleware):

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete"/>
```

To use the redirect add the following to your `app.js`

```
app.get("/:player_id", routes.showPlayer)
```

and to your `routes.js`

```
exports.showPlayer = function(req, res) {
  res.send('Details about Player ' + req.params.player_id)
}
```

Have fun creating your application!

Comment: your example works !! now I just need find a seesion handler so cna have users identify. Know a good manual book ??

Comment: can you add the views of this example ? Im getting problems with res.redirect("/" + player._id);

Comment: improved my answer. if it is helpful, you might want to accept it!